# How to store different reports in one table (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Now I want to develop reports app. So admin can create from report design and employee will fill form.

Report forms are created by the administrator and they are unique each time. Reports requested by the administrator are completed by the staff. But I would like to keep the information from the staff in the same table. I don't want to create a new MySQL table for each report form. For example:

Table 1:

| username | filldatetime | whatAreYouDoing | newColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| andrew | 2021-01-15-15:00 | marketing | newData |
| johnson | 2021-01-15-15:00 | drinking water | new Data 2 |

Table 2:

| username | filldatetime | newColumnName | AnotherColumnName | AnotherColumnName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| andrew | 2021-01-17-15:00 | some text data here | Integer data here | any data here |
| johnson | 2021-01-17-15:00 | some text data here | Integer data here... | any data here2 |

Table 3.... Table 4..... Table 5 .... infinite...

and such spreadsheets will be regularly created by the administrator from Admin panel.

How can I keep all reports from report forms in one table **without creating MySQL tables for each report form**?

How to store all data in one table without creating new tables for each report?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course store object or array type values in the table row with text type and parse them into readable object or array when you use them.

```
CREATE TABLE `templates` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `stringified_value` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

But what I suggest is like following.
It is good to have a table(templates) that identifies template type(table1, table2 from what you posted). And another table(template_data) that holds all rows of any template type.
Then, the template_data table should have a column(template_id) that says how that row can be parsed based on the template referenced from the template_id

```
CREATE TABLE `templates` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `columns` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `template_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `template_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `values` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

As you can see, columns in the templates table and values in the template_data table are still text type(actual values can be a comma-separated string), but they can be easily parsed to the array.

It is just my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

What you describe in your question is not match to RDBMS principals. If you want to save not-structured data in database - look to any [document oriented DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).